# usage of intval & real_escape_string when sanitizing integers

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

dear All.

I'm using integer PKs in some tables of mysql database. Before input from PHP script, I am doing some sanitizing, which includes intval($id) and $mysqli->real_escape_string().

The queries are quite simple

```
insert into `tblproducts`(`supplier_id`,`description`) values('$supplier_id','$description')
```

In this example, $description goes through real_escape_string(), while $supplier_id only being intval()'ed.

I'm just curious, if there're any situations, when I need to apply both intval and real_escape_string to integer I'm inserting into DB? So basically do I really need to use?

```
$supplier_id = intval($mysqli->real_escape_string($supplier_id));
```

Thank you.

Comment: All that extraneous effort with sanitizing and ensuring data types would be redundant if you were to utilize prepared statements. So much easier.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Originally DB classes were developed without prep statements, therefore I need to refactor underlying classes and not to break working infrastructure at the same time. So I am considering switching to prep statements for the reasons you mentioned, but not straight away :)

Comment: besides, prep statements, as far as i am aware, are most useful when it comes to mass queries, which is generally not the case in my situation. So basically switching to prep statements will increase (well definitely not decrease) amount of code => therefore reduced readability and performance is under question as well. To my opinion, it will be faster to do occasional intvals and real_escape_strings than prepare statement => bind => execute. Unless I will develop some kind of super-meta-db-class which will take care of all queries, which in my case would mean rewriting code from scratch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`intval` way faster than `real_escape_string` since `real_escape_string` has to connect to the database and escaping based on the charset/collation.

you can also cast the int like:

```
$val = (int)$val;
```

therefore no need to double sanitize

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use $mysqli->real_escape_string after running intval on an variable. intval() will return 0 if it is not an integer and if it is a integer it will return the value.

```
Example:
$variable = '5';
$variable2 = 'c5b';
if(intval($variable)) echo 'It is a variable'; # intval will return 5 or true
if(intval($variable2)) echo 'It is a variable'; # intval will return 0 or false since it has a letter
```

There is some cases where intval will return the first integer in the string if it is set to '5b'

Comment: intval($variable2) will return 5 not 0

Comment: I relized that and updated the answer and added it at the bottom becasue I have had it happen occasionally return 0 and other times return 5

Answer (score 1):

Consider something like this:

```
$x = "50 O'Brien Family Members at a Bar";
```

Using `intval()` will give you an "escaped" value of

```
50
```

whereas real_escape_string will give you

```
50 O\'Brien Family Members at a Bar
```

real_escape_**STRING**() should only be used where you really do want to use a string value in a query. For everything else, use a more appropriate tool.